# How to declare a constrained tuple of matching values in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, union-types

I am trying to create a pair type which only allows for matching values to be assigned from a given string union.

As a start I can already create a string union from a give const array:

```js
const allFoos = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'] as const;

// Creates a string union of ('foo' | 'bar' | 'baz')
type Foo = typeof allFoos[number];
```

Additionally, I can create a tuple which only allows members of this union to be assigned.

```js
// Creates a tuple allow any two of Foo to be assigned
type Pair = readonly [Foo, Foo];

const good: Pair = ['foo', 'bar']; // Assigns fine
const bad: Pair = ['foo', 'zzz']; // Compile error
```

Ideally, I would like a **tuple type that only allows for the same value** to be allowed.

Obviously I can specify this by handwriting all outcomes:

```js
type HandWrittenMatchedPair = 
  | readonly ['foo', 'foo']
  | readonly ['bar', 'bar']
  | readonly ['baz', 'baz'];

const good: HandWrittenMatchedPair = ['foo', 'foo']; // Assigns fine
const bad: HandWrittenMatchedPair = ['foo', 'baz']; // Compile error
```

Handwriting all variants gets less viable the more elements are added. Also for N element tuples it becomes even more tedious so **ideally these types should be generated**:

```js
// How to do this without handwriting every possibility?
type MatchedPair = [???]; 

// Ideal outcome
const good: MatchedPair = ['foo', 'foo']; // Should assign fine
const bad: MatchedPair = ['foo', 'bar']; // Should result in compile error
```

Is what I am trying do even possible?

Comment: You could also do it using generics: `type MatchedPair<T> = [T, T]` https://tsplay.dev/wO1Pdm

Comment: There is no way in the type system to have a simple type where a value at index 1, must match a value at index 0. You'd need a generic type like @vighnesh153 says, and a way to provide that generic type parameter `T` from somewhere.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Wz7O3w) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes this is exactly what I was looking for. Please write up an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to define `Pair` so that it automatically *distributes* the "turn `T` into  `readonly [T, T]`" operation over the `Foo` [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).  There are a few ways to do this:

Since `Foo`'s members are key-like (the string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"foo"`, `"bar"`, and `"baz"` can be keys of an object), you can write a *distributive object type* (as coined in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109)), which is where you make a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over the members as if they are object keys, and then immediately [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) that mapped type to get a union of property values.  Like this:

```
type Pair = { [T in Foo]:
    readonly [T, T]
}[Foo]
```

Or, for arbitrary unions (whose members might not be keylike), you can write a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) where the checked type is a generic type parameter, like this:

```
type Pair = Foo extends infer T ? T extends unknown ? (
    readonly [T, T]
) : never : never
```

(Note that in the above, `T` is a generic type parameter, while `Foo` is *not* a generic type parameter.  You cannot shorten that to `Foo extends unknown ? readonly [Foo, Foo] : never`.  The whole reason I use [conditional type `infer`ence](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) is to copy `Foo` to a generic type parameter `T` so that the inner conditional type is distributive.)

Either way gives you

```
// type Pair = 
//   readonly ["foo", "foo"] | 
//   readonly ["bar", "bar"] | 
//   readonly ["baz", "baz"]
```

which will automatically update if the definition of `Foo` updates.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgGwQMRCCMC8MDaByAMzTwBoY8AjOAJ1PKoC88BdeDUSKAbgFgAofgHpBMAMLUApnCgSMcGNGoBLMAHMYAVzBLwMEARgAKQsRgAfejTznLTAJT8oATwAOEmKhBYYzt-vhInhA4YBoAthQS1My8Any+7gAKcErU3gDeuAAqMCoeaMwAXPwwpTCScAAm4AhO2WRZzPwAvjieTXzCPq5JKWnYFdVgtbgAREQgo2TjaKOsFoM1dTijVNRTMKs0czaLw8tbDBuHc-xnfGBwYbIucMDuAPJp6SVlCTDJqd6eMBIAHjIwJUMCoCFEYDkAPwQ34AiRAjBaADWYBAAHcwDBoYZXmUynsRjgsg0Oni7DBCjAwBIAG7gynUunUFpAA)

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer.
Works exactly as expected and I've learned something new about how to make a distributive object type :^)